# Subscribe users to notifications via Soft Layer API

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have a set of users that I want to subscribe to the same notifications available via the Portal.  However, as I'm automating the creation/management of these users, I also want to automate the subscription to these notifications.

I've reviewed the API documentation, searched for any examples/tutorials, and I'm still not having any luck figuring out how to accomplish this.

Any clues, or examples would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

To add the permission, execute the following request:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/[user_id]/addBulkPortalPermission
```

**Method:** POST

**Json (payload):**

```
{
  "parameters": [
    [
      {
        "keyName": "NTF_SUBSCRIBER_MANAGE"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

To get the user permissions, execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/[ User_Customer_ID]/getPermissions
```

**References:**
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer

**EDIT:**

Follow these steps to subscribe notifications to a customer user:

**Example:** Add “PLANNED_MAINTENANCE” notification subscription.

**1.** Create a notification subscription record for the user using: SoftLayer_User_Customer::addNotificationSubscriber

**URL:**

```
https://[username:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/[user_customer_id]/addNotificationSubscriber
```

**Method:** POST

**Json (payload):**

```
{
  "parameters": [
    " PLANNED_MAINTENANCE"
  ]
}
```

**Reference:**

```
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/addNotificationSubscriber
```

**2.** Create delivery methods for a notification that the user is subscribed to (SoftLayer_User_Customer::createSubscriberDeliveryMethods).

**URL:**

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/[user_customer_id]/createSubscriberDeliveryMethods
```

**Method:** POST

**Json (payload):**

```
{
  "parameters": [
    "PLANNED_MAINTENANCE",
    [
       "EMAIL"

    ]
  ]
}
```

To get information about “notificationKeyName”  and “deliveryMethodKeyNames”, execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getActiveNotificationSubscribers?objectMask=mask[id, notification, active,deliveryMethods[notificationDeliveryMethod[active,keyName],notificationSubscriber]]
```

**Reference:**

```
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/createSubscriberDeliveryMethods
```

Comment: Thanks, but it appears that this will allow me to create users with the permission to manage subscriptions.  However, I want to actually want to subscribe some new users to one or more types of notifications.

Comment: @Joe_1577790, I made some edits to address your needs.